# Message BOX not showing up on InfoPath form

Tags: c#, messagebox, infopath

The message box should appear when the view is switched on the form but the screen comes up blank? I'm not sure why. I tried adding a reference to `Windows.Forms` as well

```
 using Microsoft.Office.InfoPath;
 using System;
 using System.Xml;
 using System.Windows.Forms;
 using System.Xml.XPath;

namespace Form1
{
    public partial class FormCode
    {
      public void InternalStartup()
      {
      }

      public static DialogResult FormEvents_ViewSwitched(object sender, ViewSwitchedEventArgs e)
      {
        string string1 = "Error";
        string string2 = "Empty field found on form";
        // Set button of type "MessageBoxButton" 
        MessageBoxButtons button = MessageBoxButtons.YesNo;
        // Static method, referenced without an object but just using the class 
        return (MessageBox.Show(string1, string2, button));
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: what happens when you remove the MesageBoxButtons completely and try the following 
`return(MessageBox.Show(string1, string2, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);`

Comment: Nothing is happening still. The view switches however, the message box does now appear.

Comment: well at least I fixed your first / initial issue with the MessageBox not displaying properly.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the following

```
MessageBox.Show("Display Error Message Text Here", "Title that appears on MessageBox here", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
```

also google how to use string.Format or string.Join or string.Concat for your message